# Using GPUImage with AVVideoCompositing

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, gpuimage

I'm trying to use a combination of `GPUImage` and the `AVVideoCompositing` to implement a live chroma-key filter between two videos. Doing this naively using `CIImage` `imageFromCVPixelBuffer` into `CGImage` into `GPUImage` out to `CGImage` to `CIImage` to `CVPixelBuffer`, is highly inefficient and leads to memory problems.

I noticed there are texture objects, render targets, and frame buffers in the `GPUImage` Framework. I was hoping to be able to leverage `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` in iOS to keep everything on the GPU.

I don't think I'm quite understanding the framework's inner workings, because I assumed I could set up a filter chain on a `GPUImageTextureInput` object and then get the filter's `renderTarget`, which is a `CVPixelBufferRef`. The `renderTarget` below is always nil, and calling `imageFromCurrentFrameBuffer` will yield me a gray box, which is not my image.

Please note that the below example is not chroma-key, but a simple brightness filter on a single video to try and prove the concept.

```
@implementation MyCustomCompositor : NSObject <AVVideoCompositing>

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, [GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext].context, NULL, &_textureCache);
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)requiredPixelBufferAttributesForRenderContext
{
    return @{(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @[@(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)],
             (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey : @YES};
}

- (NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)sourcePixelBufferAttributes
{
    return @{(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @[@(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)],
             (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey : @YES};
}

- (void)startVideoCompositionRequest:(AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest *)asyncVideoCompositionRequest
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CVPixelBufferRef mePixelBuffer = [asyncVideoCompositionRequest sourceFrameByTrackID:200];
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(mePixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);

        CVOpenGLESTextureRef meTextureRef = NULL;
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(mePixelBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(mePixelBuffer);
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCache, mePixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_BGRA, (int)width, (int)height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &meTextureRef);

        GPUImageTextureInput *meTextureInput = [[GPUImageTextureInput alloc] initWithTexture:CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(meTextureRef) size:CGSizeMake(width, height)];

        GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
        filter.brightness = 0.5;
        [meTextureInput addTarget:filter];

        [filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput *imageOutput, CMTime time) {
            [asyncVideoCompositionRequest finishWithComposedVideoFrame:((GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)imageOutput).renderTarget];
        }];

        [meTextureInput processTextureWithFrameTime:kCMTimeZero];

        CFRelease(meTextureRef);
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_textureCache, 0);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(mePixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
    }
}
```

I am not using the `GPUMovieWriter` or video APIs in `GPUImage` because I need more granular control of my composition. The composition can be made up of multiple chroma-key instructions that reference a different green video overlay at different time ranges, and it seems to me that the movie APIs in `GPUImage` are limited to filtering an entire video file. I also need the composition's abilities to manipulate tracks and audio mixes.

I've tried wrapping my head around doing all of this in GL with custom shaders, but I figured I'd leverage existing frameworks that seem to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class named GPUImageFrameInput modified from GPUImageMovie.
CVPixelBufferRef is its input.
It goes like that:

1. wrap sourcePixelBuffer to GPUImageFrameOutput
2. create GPUImageFrameInput wrapped the destinationPixelBuffer
3. complete the filter chain
4. done

Here is the key code.

```
// output 
// wrap the sourcePixelBuffer from the request
// it's modified from GPUImageVideoCamera
@interface GPUImageFrameOutput() {

}
-(void)processSourcePixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer withSampleTime:(CMTime)currentSampleTime;
@end

@implement GPUImageFrameOutput()

-(void)processSourcePixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer withSampleTime:(CMTime)currentSampleTime {
    runSynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue(^{
        [GPUImageContext useImageProcessingContext];

        int bufferHeight = (int) CVPixelBufferGetHeight(movieFrame);
        int bufferWidth = (int) CVPixelBufferGetWidth(movieFrame);

        if (bufferHeight == 0 || bufferWidth == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // almost same as 
        // [GPUImageVideoCamera processVideoSampleBuffer:]
        // 
}

@end

// input 
// wrap the destinationPixelBuffer 
@interface GPUImageFrameInput() {
    CVPixelBufferRef targetBuffer;
    // ... others
}
@end

- (void)setPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)buffer{
    targetBuffer = buffer;
}

- (CVOpenGLESTextureRef)createDataFBO {
    if (!movieFramebuffer) {
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
       glGenFramebuffers(1, &movieFramebuffer);
       glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, movieFramebuffer);
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, movieFramebuffer);
    glViewport(0, 0, (int)_videoSize.width, (int)_videoSize.height);

    CVOpenGLESTextureRef renderTexture = nil;

    if ([GPUImageContext supportsFastTextureUpload]) {
        CVBufferSetAttachment(targetBuffer, kCVImageBufferColorPrimariesKey, kCVImageBufferColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2, kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
        CVBufferSetAttachment(targetBuffer, kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrixKey, kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4, kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
        CVBufferSetAttachment(targetBuffer, kCVImageBufferTransferFunctionKey, kCVImageBufferTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2, kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);

        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (kCFAllocatorDefault, [[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] coreVideoTextureCache],
                                                  targetBuffer,
                                                  NULL, // texture attributes
                                                  GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                  GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                                  (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(targetBuffer),
                                                  (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(targetBuffer),
                                                  GL_BGRA, // native iOS format
                                                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                  0,
                                                  &renderTexture);

        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(renderTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture));
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture), 0);
    }
    else
    {
     //...
    }
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    NSAssert(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, @"Incomplete filter FBO: %d", status);

    return renderTexture;
}
```

then you can create the gpuimage chain like others

```
[frameInput setPixelBuffer:destinationPixelBuffer];

for (...) {
    GPUImageMovieFrameOutput *output ...
    [output addTarget:filter atTextureLocation:index];
}
[filter addTarget:frameInput];
```

hope helpful!

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. This looks like the code almost right out of GPUImageMovie, which is fine, but how to adapt this to a GPUImageOutput subclass? How does the call to createDataFBO happen? Or am I missing some pieces on how to arrange this subclass? I assume I would end up calling createDataFBO and assigning that ref to something?

Comment: sorry. I forgot to give the output. :P Let me fix it.

Comment: I'm still not seeing where createDataFBO is being called from - could you please clarify?